# Cant get my GoogleMap to animate to a point

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

So i am fairly new with writing android code and i have been reading the book "Hello, Android" the third edition by Ed Burnette. I was curious and decided to program the GPS section to a map. so i followed the code here initially. http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android . in that mobiforge example he provides his own longitude and latitude. but i wanted to mix it with the GPS from the book.

I was able to compile and run the code i wrote. However even sending the longitude and latitude via the emulator control the code just refuses to animate to and zoom in. So i am curious why my code does not animate and zoom in.

I have tried looking through the documentation to see if i was missing anything to solve this issue. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html and code. google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html but it all seemed to say that i had the appropriate stuff. so i don't know if I'm just missing something.

```
package org.example.GoogleMaps;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GoogleMaps extends MapActivity implements LocationListener
{    
MapView mapView;
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
LocationManager mgr;
String best;
Location location;
Double lng;
Double lat;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);      

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    best = mgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(best);
    dumpLocation(location);


}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  dumpLocation(location);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      log("\nProvider disabled: " + provider);
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  log("\nProvider enabled: " + provider);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
     Bundle extras) {
  log("\nProvider status changed: " + provider + ", status = something" + ", extras=" + extras);
}

private void dumpLocation(Location location) {
      if (location == null)
          log("location = null");
      else
      {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();


            mc = mapView.getController();
            p = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));

            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(15); 
      }

}

private void log(String string) {
      Toast.makeText(this, string, 6000);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't use [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) to start a location provider.  Use [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

```
mgr.requestLocationUpdates(best, 0, 0, this);
```

I found this blog entry very helpful in understanding how to get location: [Deep Dive into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html)

You are also missing `mc = mapView.getController();` in onCreate().

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem earlier,

1. Make sure you have used the `getcontroller` Method it should look like this 
   `mc = mapView.getController();`.
2. Make sure you have generated the Android Maps API key and included it in the `main.xml` file.